# What is the "Shaped Charge" (LW2) supposed to be good for?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-long-war-2

From the ingame descriptions:

> "A small directed explosive designed to knock down walls."
>
> "The Shaped Charge has a limited range and area of effect and will not cause injuries, even when loaded in a Grenade Launcher. It is very loud and will alert nearby enemies. For the purposes of perks, it is treated as a support grenade."
>
> "Destroys environmental objects."

So I guess its meant to provide alternative means to get into or out of a building because most grenades in LW2 do no longer cause sufficient/predictable environmental damage?

Is there any other, may more specific use case? Does it destroy environmental object that are indestructible otherwise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly for extreme environmental damage!

It destroys pretty much everything (except maybe some load bearing pylons) but it has a very short range so it's kind of a high risk - high reward situation.

I usually use it when I have enemies concentrated in a spot, behind heavy cover, who just won't die. I approach, expose my soldier and throw the grenade betting on the fact that I will absolutely kill everyone after they're exposed! (risky bet)

You can also read about [The Shaped Charge in real life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaped_charge).

Comment: Hmm, sapper grenades are already pretty effective against cover, have much larger radius AND do damage. So I am still not convinced that shaped charges are so useful. I suppose it won't blow up the outside wall of prison cells? It would be pretty cool not having to go inside the building to unlock the doors in some missions :)

Comment: Hmm thinking about "sapper", the shaped charge would allow to choose "needle grenades" from the grenadier skill tree and compensate the missing destructive effect of "sapper" by taking a shaped charge with him.

Comment: Never tried it against a prison cell. I might give it a go and let you know.

Comment: It does also _not_ destroy the Relays in the Destroy Relay missions!

Comment: I've tried it for jailbreak missions. It's hit and miss, you can end up burning the prisoners as it will set tiles on fire. In theory it's a good idea, in practice not so much.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Notice that you get the shaped charge right off the bat (before you have Sapper traits), and also that _non-grenadiers_ can carry the shaped charge.

Answer (score 4):

The Grenadier grenades are ideal for combat but they don't always destroy high cover.  Shaped charge is ideal for a specific task.  Jails usually have few entry points and sneaking your squad as close to the objective as possible before breaking concealment is ideal. Getting your squad into position and using this tool can make ambush and run or no fire tactics more viable for an extraction.

Comment: I think OP was mainly wanting to know about uses *other* than destroying walls/creating openings.